# Creating a list using for and list comprehension

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I would like to create a list numbers, that will be:

```
[[1,2,3,..,n]
[n+1,n+2,...,2n]
...
[n*(m-1)+1, n*(m-1)+2,..., n*m]]
```

For exemple, for m==2 and n==3, output would be:

```
[[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]]
```

I achieved to create a list like this using :

```
Result=[]
List=[]
for i in range(1,n*m+1):
    if (i)%(n+1)==0:
        Result.append(List)
        List=[]
        print(i)

    List.append(i)
Result.append(List)
print(Result)
```

But is there a simplier way to do it ? Maybe using list comprehension ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This Could be your answer:

```py
[list(range(j-n+1, j+1)) for j in range(n, n*m+1, n)]
```

## Input

```py
n = 3
m = 3
```

## output:

```py
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
n = 4
m = 5

[list(range(1+k*n, 1+(k+1)*n)) for k in range(m+1)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [5, 6, 7, 8],
 [9, 10, 11, 12],
 [13, 14, 15, 16],
 [17, 18, 19, 20],
 [21, 22, 23, 24]]
```